# Accept prompt number input + print String

Tags: string, for-loop, prompt

Im trying to create a string output using numbers.
User enters a number + corresponding string is output

My code seems off + also is there a way to use for/while loop to make this neater?

```
//Single input
let num = prompt("Please enter a number");


//Comparing if
if (num === 1)
{
   console.log("Mon");
} 
else if (num === 2)
{
  console.log ("Tue");
}
else if (num === 3)
{
  console.log ("Wedn");
}
else if (num === 4)
{
  console.log ("Thurs");
}
else if (num === 5)
{
  console.log ("Frid");
}
else if (num === 6)
{
  console.log ("Satu");
}
else if (num === 7)
{
  console.log ("Sund");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let num = prompt("Please enter a number");` returns a **string**, not a **number**, you'd have to convert the result to number.

One way to do it:

```
let num = +prompt("Please enter a number"); // note the plus sign before prompt
```

or

```
let num = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"));
```

```js
//Single input
let num = +prompt("Please enter a number");


//Comparing if
if (num === 1)
{
   console.log("Mon");
} 
else if (num === 2)
{
  console.log ("Tue");
}
else if (num === 3)
{
  console.log ("Wedn");
}
else if (num === 4)
{
  console.log ("Thurs");
}
else if (num === 5)
{
  console.log ("Frid");
}
else if (num === 6)
{
  console.log ("Satu");
}
else if (num === 7)
{
  console.log ("Sund");
}
```

Regarding making this neater?

```js
const daysOfTheWeek = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wedn", "Thurs", "Frid", "Satu", "Sund"];
const day = +prompt("Please enter a number");

if(day > 0 && day <= daysOfTheWeek.length){
    console.log(daysOfTheWeek[day - 1]);
} else {
    console.log("No such day");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way would be to use a map to look up the days given a number. E.g.

```
let days = {
  1: "Mon",
  2: "Tue",
  3: "Wed",
  4: "Thur",
  5: "Fri",
  6: "Sat",
  7: "Sun",
}


let num = prompt("Please enter a number");
console.log(days[num])
```